# Errors with repeated FFTW calls

Tags: transform, fft, fftw

I'm having a strange issue that I can't resolve. I made this as a simple example that demonstrates the problem. I have a sine wave defined between [0, 2*pi]. I take the Fourier transform using FFTW. Then I have a for loop where I repeatedly take the inverse Fourier transform. In each iteration, I take the average of my solution and print the results. I expect that the average stays the same with each iteration because there is no change to solution, y. However, when I pick N = 256 and other even values of N, I note that the average grows as if there are numerical errors. However, if I choose, say, N = 255 or N = 257, this is not the case and I get what is expect (avg = 0.0 for each iteration).

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  int N = 256;
  double dx = 2.0 * M_PI / (double)N, dt = 1.0e-3;
  double *x, *y;

  x = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * N); 
  y = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * N);

  // initial conditions
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = (double)i * dx;
    y[i] = sin(x[i]);
  }

  fftw_complex yhat[N/2 + 1];
  fftw_plan fftwplan, fftwplan2;    

  // forward plan
  fftwplan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, y, yhat, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(fftwplan);

  // set N/2th mode to zero if N is even
  if (N % 2 < 1.0e-13) {
    yhat[N/2][0] = 0.0;
    yhat[N/2][1] = 0.0;
  }

  // backward plan
  fftwplan2 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(N, yhat, y, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    // yhat to y  
    fftw_execute(fftwplan2);

    // rescale
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      y[j] = y[j] / (double)N;
    }

    double avg = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      avg += y[j];
    }
    printf("%.15f\n", avg/N);
  }

  fftw_destroy_plan(fftwplan);
  fftw_destroy_plan(fftwplan2);
  void fftw_cleanup(void);
  free(x);
  free(y);
  return 0;
}
```

Output for N = 256:

```
0.000000000000000
0.000000000000000
0.000000000000000
-0.000000000000000
0.000000000000000
0.000000000000022
-0.000000000000007
-0.000000000000039
0.000000000000161
-0.000000000000314
0.000000000000369
0.000000000004775
-0.000000000007390
-0.000000000079126
-0.000000000009457
-0.000000000462023
0.000000000900855
-0.000000000196451
0.000000000931323
-0.000000009895302
0.000000039348379
0.000000133179128
0.000000260770321
-0.000003233551979
0.000008285045624
-0.000016331672668
0.000067450106144
-0.000166893005371
0.001059055328369
-0.002521514892578
0.005493164062500
-0.029907226562500
0.093383789062500
-0.339111328125000
1.208251953125000
-3.937500000000000
13.654296875000000
-43.812500000000000
161.109375000000000
-479.250000000000000
1785.500000000000000
-5369.000000000000000
19376.000000000000000
-66372.000000000000000
221104.000000000000000
-753792.000000000000000
2387712.000000000000000
-8603776.000000000000000
29706240.000000000000000
-96833536.000000000000000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libfftw` has the odious habit of modifying its inputs. Back up `yhat` if you want to do repeated inverse transforms.

OTOH, it's perverse, but why are you repeating the same operation if you don't expect it give different results? (Despite this being the case)

Comment: Well, in the actual code the results are supposed to change (each iteration modifies yhat) but I run into the same issue where the solution for even N grows while odd N gives the right result. Here, I wanted to make the example as simple as possible.

However, I guess the fact that yhat changes in the real problem with each iteration means that I can't use a single back up.

Comment: If you want to keep the input data unchanged, use the `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` flag.  Per http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html

Comment: I modified the `c2r` plan to contain `FFTW_ESTIMATE | FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` and it seems to have done the trick both here and in my real problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the doco, I couldn't find that. C2r is destructive by default. FFTW is now a little less odious in my book.

Comment: Can you write this up as an answer @symmetric and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in comments: "if you want to keep the input data unchanged, use the `FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT` flag. Per http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html"

For example:

```
// backward plan
fftwplan2 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(N, yhat, y, FFTW_ESTIMATE | FFTW_PRESERVE_INPUT);
```